# Apple calendar API endpoints

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, google-calendar-api

I am using Google calendar API with nodejs to edit events in users calendar. My users use oauth2 flow to give me access to their Google calendars, they just clicked auth link in Telegram bot and provide my Google service access to their calendar. With access token I make requests for certain Google calendar API, [for example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get).

Apple has Oauth2 flow and I have found [guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple) how to get access token and other credentials, but its just for "sign in with Apple" and I have found **nothing** about URLs to access to Apple calendar.
There is apple framework [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit), but its only SWIFT language.

So, my question is where can I get apple calendar URLs to make request with received access token?

Comment: There are no publicly available iCloud calendar endpoints.  Sign in With Apple provides a way for your app to leverage a secure and privacy-aware user authentication system, but it does not provide any access to the user's Apple services.

Comment: @Paulw11, Is there any way to get access to user's Apple services like with Google API? or I can get access to Apple calendar only from Apple app using EventKit ?

Comment: There are no published web APIs for iCloud calendars. EventKit allows you to access all calendars on a device, whether they are local or from another provider including iCloud, Google, Exchange, Office365 etc.